# PHP Place each word in a paragraph in a <span> without punctuation

Tags: php

How do I place each word in a paragraph in its individual span tag? Currently I am using explode() and using a space to do this, but the I get the following:

```
"<span>Hello,</span> <span>I</span> <span>am</span> <span>Alec.</span>"
```

I will be using a dictionary lookup for each word, but "Hello," will not find what I'm looking for. Furthermore, I am stylizing the span depending on the word selected (through an onClick), so I don't want the comma to be part of the span.

Eventually, I want the following code to populate:

```
"<span>Hello</span>, <span>I</span> <span>am</span> <span>Alec</span>."
```

Theoretically it would be nice to do this without using explode() since I have to add all of these characters back into the text, but outside of the `<span>`. Is there a function to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Edit: I will be using this for everyday writing in different languages, so hyphenated words or letters outside of "A-Za-z" are expected.

Comment: You should include the code you currently use in your question.

Comment: Well considering the code that I am currently using is described above and does not accomplish what I would like, I do not agree.

If it would so make you happy, it is explode(" ", $variable);

Comment: You can do it with `preg_replace`

Comment: We cannot help you solve your issue without knowing exactly what has been tried. Simply describing how you do offers little as there are many different solutions to the same problem. Also, you have tagged this as PHP, but not included any PHP code. It is more like a generic question as of now

Comment: Sounds like you need a regular expression, maybe using word boundaries. Note that these might change depending on the language. Read more at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @AnotherGuy Agreed. I posted a comment (soon as the question came out) asking the OP to post his PHP but gotten no response so I removed it. Now he's telling us if it makes us happy *"it is explode(" ", $variable);"* which leaves it up to a lot of guesswork.

Comment: @AlecO'Connor You have an answer below now, ask them. If it works, *great*.

Comment: Hi all, the purpose of me asking this questions was that the code that I was using, explode(), was not doing what I wanted it to do. Mitkosoft's answer helped me solve my problem. I did not include my code because I needed to look up a new method. While the preg_replace() was my solution, simply that did not help me solve my problem. Mitkosoft's code was simple and complete and actually answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace()` can do that:

```
$str = 'Hello, I am Alec.';
echo preg_replace('/(\w+)/', '<span>${1}</span>', $str);
```

Output:

```
<span>Hello</span>, <span>I</span> <span>am</span> <span>Alec</span>.
```